# Battery with high risk of being exposed to fire

Tags: batteries, battery-chemistry

I'm currently working on an electronic design which has a high risk of being exposed to temperatures up to 500°C and possibly more.

The specifications indicate that once the product is exposed to more than 80°C it needs to be replaced by a new one, so the electronics don't need to be qualified over typical industrial range temperatures.

I still have a problem with the energy source. I don't have big hopes that the client will let me design a system with a wireless charger linked to the standard power network, so I need to come up with ideas about batteries that will not explode when exposed to fire.

I need 2.5V or more, for 1 Ah.

Do batteries which won't explode exist/are currently publicly available or should I ask for help about thermal isolation to slow down the temperature rise for hours?

My electronic device is supposed to sense different parameters (like pressure, shocks,...) and log data  locally to be gathered regularly through NFC. For the enclosure, I could say based on the mechanical model I got 50x100x100 mm. Expected operating time is 6 months.

Comment: I would be interested to find out if anyone has experience with high temperature battery’s just out of personal curiosity. Few comments to further your description, how big of an enclosure are we talking about? & what’s the expected operation time? What sort of capacity will the battery require? You could also consider using Peltier devices to control the battery temperature in the battery enclosure. I suspect going down the thermally isolating enclosure route with some fire retardant UL94-0V material will be the solution

Comment: My electronic device is supposed to sense different parameters (like pressure, shocks,...) and log datas in local to be gathered regularly through NFC.
For the enclosure, I could say based on the mecanical model I got 50x100x100 mm. But they said they could accept larger dimensiosn if needed.
Expected operating time is 6 months I guess. But it will depend on the feasability study. The client can adapt his maintenance schedule. About capacity, I would be happy with 1AH. I didn't calculated consumptions now.

Comment: What voltage do you need?

Comment: 3,7V would be good. All the electronics I've selected can be powered at 2,5V.

Comment: good ole lead acid and coal-zinc won't explode if vented properly, I'd guess. Convince your client that you need to put the power source outside of your furnace or volcano or whatever this is, for safety and environmental reasosn :)

Comment: @Prof_Sims also, what you gave here in the comments is very crucial design info, so I added it to your question.

Comment: I believe that you need insulation to limit the temperature rise for hours. You need a fire safe or several of them.

Comment: I'd go for wireless power especially if it's a rotating machine you are sensing.

Comment: What do you consider an explosion? Batteries of that capacity are generally designed to vent if pressure builds up internally. Profiling certain thermal processes involves similar requirements.

Comment: @SpehroPefany. An explosion for me could be violent. Creating a danger for someone in a close area or even firefighters in when the highest temperatures are involved. I'm afraid that the product could be refused because of this risk.